# Flask Python pass data on link click

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a recipes database.  My issue is with showing the result of a search.  I can search the database by ingredient and get a list of recipes with that ingredient.  I display those results on a new page; I show just the title of the recipe and I make it a link to a 'showrecipe' page.  But I cannot find a way to send the recipe id to the new page so it knows which recipe to show.  Here are the relevant bits of code so far:

The Search Form:

```
class SearchIngredientsForm(FlaskForm):
    ingredients_string = StringField('ingredients_string', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1)])
    # search_string = StringField('Search string', [InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

and the search route:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchIngredientsForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        search_ingredients_string = form.ingredients_string
        search_ingredients_list = search_ingredients_string.data.split(',')
        recipe_ids = []
        ingredient_objects = []

        if search_ingredients_list:
            for ingredient_name in search_ingredients_list:
                ingredient_objects.extend( Ingredient.query.filter(Ingredient.line.like(f'%{ingredient_name}%')).all() )
                if ingredient_objects:
                    for ingredient in ingredient_objects:
                        recipe_ids.append(ingredient.recipe_id)
        session['recipe_ids'] = recipe_ids
        return redirect(url_for('results'))
    return render_template('search.html', form=form)
```

and the results.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Results</h1>
    {% for result in recipe_objects %}
        <a href= "{{ url_for('showrecipe'), id=result.id }}">{{ result.title }} which serves: {{ result.serves }}</a>      
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and finally the showrecipe route.  I cannot seem to get the id to pass through.

```
@app.route('/showrecipe/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def showrecipe(id):
    recipe = Recipe.query.get(id)
    return render_template('showrecipe.html', recipe=recipe)
```

When I click on the recipe title on the results page I get a 'url not found' error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update**

Here is the results route:

```
@app.route('/results')
def results():
    recipe_ids = session.get('recipe_ids')
    recipe_objects = []
    if recipe_ids:
        for recipe_id in recipe_ids:
            recipe_objects.append(Recipe.query.get(recipe_id)) 
    return render_template('results.html', recipe_objects=recipe_objects)
```

Comment: What does your "results" route look like? You'll simplify your life if you just return the results page right there, and then in your results template include the "id" in the "url_for" call.

Comment: @tedivm, do you mean show the results on the search page, or show the clicked recipe on the results page?

Comment: This was the problem:  include the "id" in the "url_for" call.  Thank you.